# Accessing remote mysql server using port forwarding without editing my.cnf

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ssh, portforwarding

A(remote mysql server) <-------> B( remote Staging server) <--------> C(my laptop)

mysql server is running on machine A having IP 192.168.39.151. There is another remote server B having IP 192.168.33.150 which can access mysql server running on A.

machine C is my laptop and my intension is to access mysql server and I dont have the access. So every time I have to ssh to B(staging server) to access mysql server.

Can it be possible to access mysql server from C(my laptop) without login into B(Staging server) so my python scripts can work on my laptop itself?

I guess port forwarding is the solution. Can somebody tell me the steps to setup port forwarding for this case. all the machines re running on Linux.

Please tell me if there are other solutions.

Comment: where does python come into the mix?  Are you accessing mysql with it?

Comment: yes @16num , ultimately I have run the scripts which connects to the mysql server.